# Adicionar coluna como Primary Key

Tags: sql-server

Rodei o seguinte Script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[horario](
    [Ano] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CodigoTurma] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [Ordem] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Professor_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Matriz_Semestre] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Matriz_Curso_Codigo] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [Matriz_Disciplina_Codigo] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [primary key1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Ano] ASC,
    [Professor_Id] ASC,
    [Matriz_Semestre] ASC,
    [Matriz_Curso_Codigo] ASC,
    [Matriz_Disciplina_Codigo] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Não posso remover a tabela criada, então, para acrescentar uma nova coluna rodei o seguinte comando:

```
ALTER TABLE horario ADD Dia [int] NOT NULL
```

O problema é que preciso que essa nova coluna também faça parte do conjunto `primary key`. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Por algum motivo o banco ficou assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta derrubar a chave primária e criá-la de novo:

```
ALTER TABLE horario
DROP CONSTRAINT [primary key1]
GO

ALTER TABLE horario
ADD CONSTRAINT [primary key1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [Ano] ASC,
    [Professor_Id] ASC,
    [Matriz_Semestre] ASC,
    [Matriz_Curso_Codigo] ASC,
    [Matriz_Disciplina_Codigo] ASC,
    [Dia] ASC
)
GO
```

Para conferir o nome da chave primária, use:

```
SELECT * from 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS Tab
WHERE 
    Tab.Table_Name = 'horario'
    AND Constraint_Type = 'PRIMARY KEY'
```

Comment: Você como sempre sendo fera @Cigano, muito obrigado meu amigo. Mas infelizmente retornou um **erro**: `'key1' is not a constraint.`, mas não entendi o porquê...

Comment: No `DROP` ou no `ADD`?

Comment: o `Drop` ......

Comment: Confira o nome da chave, se é `key1` mesmo.

Comment: Bem, no script está exatamente key1 mesmo, mas existe alguma forma de ser feita a verificação no próprio banco com algum comando?

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta...

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues A query anterior só deu o nome das colunas, então coloquei outra query que pode ser mais útil.

Comment: O resultado foi `CONSTRAINT_NAME = primary key1` atualizei a pergunta...

Comment: Descobri, basta usar: [primary key1] com colchetes no nome!